# Is the clutch in automatic transmission gearboxes unduly used, as with manual transmission, when a car is driven at ultra low speeds?

Tags: automatic-transmission, clutch, manual-transmission

I have yet to understand how an automatic transmission gearbox works (*not* CVT—those are trivial). This question is an attempt to figure out a small piece of the puzzle.

Properly handled, the clutch in a manual transmission car can last hundreds of thousands of kilometers/miles, but one action in particular overly abrades the surface. A driver who needs to proceed extremely slowly on flat ground will keep the clutch semi-released. Dropping the engine's RPM would result in stalling. This semi-released state will wear out the clutch faster than it needs to.

(The other method, to inject a bit of speed on first gear, then release the clutch, and repeat, isn't always suitable if one, say, is going through a tight passage.)

Is the clutch in automatic transmission gearboxes unduly used, as with manual transmission, when a car is driven at very low speeds?

(I understand that some automatic transmission gearboxes have 2 or more clutches. Still, only one clutch is responsible for moving from standstill.)

##### Related

- [Durability of automatic transmission boxes versus durability of manual transmission boxes? Their lifetimes?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/6276/57044)

Comment: Presumably you mean a DSG auto gearbox, not the 1950's design still fitted to some vehicles. It might depend on whether the clutch is a wet or dry one. VAG gearboxes have used both. But what percentage of your driving is done with a slipping clutch like that? I would have thought the more typical use case would be crawling in traffic, when you allow the vehicle to creep forwards against the brake.